# HTTP GET request using start and end date in couch db

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have a database which have information regarding the device logs. I am able to pull the device logs details using the device id as follows.

```
http://localhost:5984/device-log/_design/DeviceLog/_view/by_device_id?include_docs=true&descending=true&key=%22000000a20040c656ea%22
```

I would like to filter the device logs using a start and end date. It would be great if get the query using the dates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is a little confusing. Are you using Couchbase or Cloudant? If you are using Couchbase, does this URL point to Sync Gateway?

Comment: I am using couch base db and I am new to it and the URL is not point to Sync Gateway. The above get request will returns all the device logs based on the supplied device id. I would like to read the device logs for a particular time period by passing START and END dates.

Comment: I see that you removed the Couchbase tag, so I'm more confused. Port 5984 is not typically used by Couchbase. Are you sure you're using Couchbase and not CouchDB/Cloudant?

Comment: I am using couch db. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you show us how your log document look like?